# Call to a member function markQuotesRecollect() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.8, quote, totals

Whenever I try to save a product in my store I get the following error `Call to a member function markQuotesRecollect() on a non-object`

I have no idea where this came from or how to fix it, it wasn't there before. I'm running Magento 8.1.1 CE

The error refers to this function

```
public function catalogProductSaveAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    if ($product->getStatus() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED) {
        return $this;
    }

    Mage::getResourceSingleton('sales/quote')->markQuotesRecollect($product->getId());

    return $this;
}
```

And specific to this rule `Mage::getResourceSingleton('sales/quote')->markQuotesRecollect($product->getId());`

Comment: I assume the call to `Mage::getResourceSingleton('sales/quote')` is not returning an object

Comment: @David Manners yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason is that there is no `sales/quote` model in the registry at this point.

Try to use the function `getResourceModel` but be aware that this will be an empty model unless you load it.

I would suggest that what you actually want to do is try to get the singleton resource and if it is not set or empty then simply do not call the function. Something like the following should work:

```
public function catalogProductSaveAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    if ($product->getStatus() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED) {
        return $this;
    }

    $quote =Mage::getResourceSingleton('sales/quote');
    if ($quote){
        $quote->markQuotesRecollect($product->getId());
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: like `Mage::getResourceModel('sales/quote')` 
(I have barely worked with the core files before and do not know much about them)

Comment: @Eddie see edit

Comment: @ David Manners Thank you it solved the error where the script stopped executing but it still returns the following error `Mage registry key "_resource_singleton/sales/quote" already exists` do you know how to solve that too?

Comment: @Eddie sorry I am a bit confused now it should not try to create the registry with the code I suggested above :(

Comment: Hi I should probaly open a new question for this, but the site isn't working anymore and im freaking out whenever you add a product to the cart the following message is displayed `Call to a member function getIdFieldName() on a non-object` Do you know how to fix it?